# How do I allocate device memory to my array of pointers, in CUDA?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I have the following data structures on my host:

```
typedef struct point{
   int x;
   int y;
}Point;

 typedef struct pair{
     Point i;
     Point j;
     float cost;
 }Pair;

Pair* pairs[n];   // allocates an array of pointers to pair
```

Now, I've to copy "pairs" to the GPU. So, I declare the following pointer:

```
Pair **d_pair;
```

and allocate the memory using the following:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)d_pair,(sizeof(Pair)+sizeof(Pair*))*n);
```

Now, I copy from host to device:

```
cudaMempy(d_pair,pair,(sizeof(Pair)+sizeof(Pair*))*n),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The kernel prototype receives d_pair as:

```
__global__ my_kernel(Pair* d_pair[], ... ){ 
...
}
```

Should the above sequence of statements work as intended? If not, what modifications I make? Basically, I want to copy Pair* pairs[n]; as such to "d_pair". How do I do this?

Comment: If you can switch to an array of `Pair`, instead of an array of pointers to `Pair`, then your data copying can be straightforward with relatively small changes to the sequence you have outlined.  Otherwise the process is considerably more complicated and will require a loop with multiple steps in it.  If you search on cuda 2D array (an array of pointers to data is effectively a 2D array) you will get an idea of the complexity.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work: you are sending an array of pointer, but not the objects themselves.
You need to have an array (or a Vector) of Pair:

```
Pair pairs[n];
```

And then :

```
Pair *d_pair;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pair,sizeof(Pair)*n);
cudaMempy(d_pair,pairs,sizeof(Pair)*n,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

By the way, this:

```
cudaMempy(d_pair,pair,(sizeof(Pair)+sizeof(Pair*))*n),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

is non sense, you allocate space for a pointer AND a Pair. Your copy use the same (sizeof(Pair)+sizeof(Pair*))*n) expression but the array pairs is (n*sizeof(Pair*)), so you are copying undefined memory.

Comment: can you please tell me what changes do I have to make to the code?